# Attributes Inspector: how to use "Stretching"

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.3

What are the numbers in the Stretching box in the View sub-box Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector?

(as a side question - I suppose a respectable company such as Apple would have actually released documentation for its tools, as opposed to letting developers just guess everything; so, where's this documentation?...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing a `.storyboard` file in a text editor (figures it's an `XML` file) revealed the answer: it is linked to `UIView`'s [contentStretch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentStretch) property.

Answer (score 4):

This blog post Karol seems to explain it pretty well. - http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/

> Stretching properties are pretty simple (I don't think so, but the
>   articles does :).
>
> The fraction of the original image left without stretching on the left
>   is specified by X The fraction of the original image that gets
>   stretched in the x-axis is specified by Width The fraction of the
>   original image left without stretching on the right is equal to 1 – X
>   – Width If we use 0  for Width  the stretched area will interpolate
>   between the last pixel of the left part and the first pixel of the
>   right part The y-axis works analogously

Answer (score 0):

FYI - this was deprecated in iOS 6.0 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentStretch

(updated link)

Comment: "Sorry, that page cannot be found."

Comment: Just in case someone else gets here(like me), [and wants an updated link to the docs stating the deprecation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentStretch).

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation Documentation

[image]

Instance Property

## contentStretch

The rectangle that defines the stretchable and nonstretchable regions of a view.

### Deprecated

> To achieve the same effect, use [resizableImageWithCapInsets](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624102-resizableimagewithcapinsets?language=objc): instead.