# What is use of stretching property of UIImageView. How I can use this property.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiimageview

[image]

I want to know how can i use this property for UIImageView.

Comment: please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13367861/1921723

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stretching properties are pretty simple, as stated by Karol Kozub in [this article](http://macoscope.com/blog/stretchable-images-using-interface-builder/):

> The fraction of the original image left without stretching on the left
>   is specified by X
>
> The fraction of the original image that gets stretched in the x-axis
>   is specified by Width
>
> The fraction of the original image left without stretching on the
>   right is equal to 1 – X – Width
>
> If we use 0  for Width  the stretched area will interpolate between
>   the last pixel of the left part and the first pixel of the right part
>
> The y-axis works analogously

Comment: Answer copied from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29000138/2227743 Please stop plagiarizing other user's answers.

Comment: Eric, please.. google is a big world. I've already faced it before. I copied the blogs statement and I refered the link. Maybe it is a terrible answer if I didn't refer the link. Or should I know all stackoverflow's answers?

Comment: This was the second time today I saw an answer of yours that contained an answer from another user. Maybe this time you copied from a blog instead of copying from a Stack Overflow answer like you did previously, ok, so it could be my mistake, but you're not a victim either. Plagiarized authors are. Let's just hope we won't find anymore copied content and all will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

This sets the `contentStretch` property for views (this is a `UIView` property, not specifically a `UIImageView` property). This property has been deprecated since iOS 6, however, so you shouldn't use it.

The replacement, specifically for images, is `resizableImageWithCapInsets`. The normal use of this is to create an image with a left and right side (or top and bottom), and a single-pixel wide "middle" that is stretched across the view. It's common for custom buttons both because it's flexible to a variety of widths, and because it saves some space.

See "Defining a Stretchable Image" in the [UIImage docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html) for full details.